# Can I turn off the alternate keyboards in Messages

Tags: iphone, keyboard

When I rotate my iPhone while in Messages, a totally different input area appears. I never use this, can I turn it off?

Comment: Related: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/253798/how-do-i-turn-off-drawing-mode-in-ios-10s-messages/263655

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about the Handwriting Input panel in iOS 10:

Rotate the phone to show the input area, then tap the keyboard icon, showing the keyboard, and it will keep the setting.

[image]

Image / info via: https://www.gottabemobile.com/how-to-turn-off-the-5-most-annoying-ios-10-features/

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know what this was called so my Google-fu failed.